# I want to update my C code with eliminating Ctype.h library

Tags: c

I have written a C code with using ctype.h library . Now i must update this code with the same output and i can't use ctype.h and string.h libraries . I think i should use new functions in it , but my math is not well and i don't know how can i do that . I searched about it but i couldn't find useful results . Can you help me to update this code ? 
This code works in this way : When i give a reverse sentence to it , it converts my sentence to usual.

Example input: oD uoy tnaw ot eunitnoc?

output: Do you want to continue?

here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
   char sentence[100];
   int ch, i, j, k;

   for (i=0; i<sizeof(sentence)-1; i++) 
       if ((sentence[i] = getchar()) == '\n') 
           break;

   sentence[i] = '\0';

   for (j = 0; j <=i; j++)
   {
       if(sentence[j]==' ' || sentence[j]=='\0')
       {
           for( k=j-1;sentence[k]!=' ' && k>=0;k--)
           {
               ch=sentence[k];
               putchar(ch);
           }
           printf(" ");  
       }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gotta ask, "i can't use ctype.h and string.h libraries" - **why** ? They're part of the standard library specced with the language. And your question's `output`... is that what the output *should* be or what you're program *currently* does? I would think providing *both* would be beneficial to your question.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Arbitrary homework restrictions.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using ctype.

Comment: Abram that is not homework . I'm learning C and my friends are better than me in programming ( But they don't help me :( ). They said that you can write this code  without ctype.h and writing with ctype and string.h is easy . Now i want to see how can i write this code with the same output , without ctype.h and string.h libraries .

Comment: @Reza2X2X This code is works correctly without that both header files. Have you tried?

Comment: I mean write it without putchars and getchars . can you help me in this case ?

Comment: Maybe you should re-ask this question but be more specific: what you are not allowed to use and what you **are** allowed to use.  As currently stated, you said you are not allowed to use ctype.h and string.h but you already are not using any if that.  Then in the comment you said you are not allowed to use getchar and putchar.  Ok, but what are you allowed to use?  Because I could easily say scanf and printf but you probably don't want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

This code is works correctly without that both header files. Have you tried? – Karthikeyan.R.S